# Are there errors in purely integer multiplication?

Tags: floating-point, int, multiplication

I know there are errors in floating point multiplication but are there errors in purely integer multiplication? Let's say I'm using Python, how large of integers A and B can I compute A*B and get answers that are exactly right? where is the wall? Also the same with addition?

Comment: overflow is very very easy to hit.  take two 8 bit numbers 0x02*0xFF=0xFE is the wrong answer.  to get the right answer your result needs twice as many bits 0xFF * 0xFF = 0xFE01, so if you want to do N bit multiplication use N*2 bit integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no error in (correct) floating-point multiplication.  Rounding may occur, but that’s not an error, that’s the defined behavior of the arithmetic.  Colloquially this is called “rounding error”, but it is not an “error” in the normal sense of the word.

There is no error in (correct) integer multiplication.  In some languages, overflow may occur, but that’s not an error, that’s the defined behavior of the arithmetic*.

In Python in particular, overflow does not occur with integer multiplication**; the result is equal to the “mathematically exact” result, and is silently promoted to a bignum if necessary.  The same holds true for addition.

[*] there are some languages where overflow produces a trap or throws an exception; again, however, that’s the defined behavior in those languages.

[**] so long as the result isn’t so large that storage for it cannot be allocated.

Comment: In C, an overflow when computing signed integers cannot reasonably be regarded as anything other than an "error", since the standards committee (very unwisely IMHO) decided that compilers authors should be given total freedom to do anything they want when integer overflow occurs, up to and including turning the CPU into a pile of molten slag [IMHO, they should have provided very great latitude, perhaps extending so far as to permit "any *Implementation-Defined* behavior", but going so far as "Undefined Behavior" is much worse].